# Image self adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

I am asked to prove the following:

For a compact self-adjoint operator T on a Hilbert Space H, show that:
$$ \operatorname{Im}(T) \mbox{ is closed} \iff \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) < \infty$$

I know that for self adjoint operators you can write them with the spectral representation. However, I am still missing a specific property about self adjoint operators that I don't know to show this. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I think that the best hint that can be given here is that you don't need self-adjointness. The statement works for arbitrary compact operator (you can assume that $T$ is a compact operator from one Banach space to another).

Comment: Open mapping thm + above comment